# Returning a list from a recursive function

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate all the permutations for an array of digits and return the return as a List. I presume that because the function is recursive I can't declare the List<> to be returned in the `DoPermute` method itself, so I have defined the List<> as a property on the `Permutation`. The code for the class looks like this:

```
class Permutation
{

    // Constructors

    public Permutation()
    {
    }

    // build permutations of input array

    public void DoPermute(ref byte[] digits, ref int n, ref int i)
    {
        if (i == n)
        {
            long temp = Numbers.JoinDigits(digits);
            Permutations.Add(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
                int temp = i + 1;
                DoPermute(ref digits, ref n, ref temp);
                SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<long> Permutations { get; set; }

}
```

I am calling the code using the following lines and I get an error.

```
 byte[] num = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 int len = num.Length;
 int zero = 0;
 Permutation p = new Permutation();
 p.DoPermute(ref num, ref len, ref zero);
 List<long> permuts = p.Permutations;
```

However, if redeclare the `DoPermute` method as static and replace `Permutations.Add(temp);` with a simple `Debug.WriteLine(temp);` I do get the correct list of permutations.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: `I presume that because the function is recursive I can't declare the List<> to be returned` - why do you make this assumption?

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: I'd avoid using a property. So you'd need to pass the list as a parameter. And that's all you need to do. Then you can use a static method.

Comment: what is the value of `permuts` in the end of the normal run ?

Comment: @oded - I thought because I'd need to declare the List<> in the recursive function itself, it would instantiate a new list each time the recurive function is called thereby losing the previous permutations stored. I may be wrong though, I'm not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - `permuts` would just be factorial(n). So for the example provided above, `permuts` would have 120 elements.

Comment: @insomniac: I understand what `permuts` should be. I'm asking what it really is? or in other words what is the problem?

Comment: Why is digits passed as `ref`? It never appears to be mutated. Remember, you only need to pass by ref if you are mutating *the variable*. It looks like you are mutating the contents of the array, not the variable that holds the reference to the array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to create the permutations list somewhere: `Permutations = new List<long>();`.

Second, if you'd prefer to have the method return the list instead of defining a public property, you could do it like this:

```
public static List<long> DoPermute(ref byte[] digits, ref int n, ref int i)
{
    List<long> permuts = new List<long>();
    DoPermuteWorker(permuts, ref digits, ref n, ref i);
    return permuts;
}

private static void DoPermuteWorker(List<long> permuts, ref byte[] digits, ref int n, ref int i)
{
    if (i == n)
    {
        long temp = Numbers.JoinDigits(digits);
        permuts.Add(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
            int temp = i + 1;
            DoPermuteWorker(permuts, ref digits, ref n, ref temp);
            SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 wrapping the recursive function this way is very clean. The worker should maybe be private though?

Comment: Oops, yes, it should be private. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - great suggestion about the DoPermute method. I'll make it private. Actually - slightly off-topic - but when should one use property/instance over static? For example, the above problem I thought would be a classic example of when to use properties.

Comment: Properties are state. That's appropriate for things that need to live for while. This is just a single simple function. Perfect for a static. No need to instantiate an instance.

Comment: Understood, in fact that exactly was what I was trying to do initially - get a stateless way of generating the list. Thanks again for the help, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code fails with a null reference exception because you never instantiate the list. You should do so in your constructor.

However, I'd prefer this as a static method. It feels wrong to me to be using a property for your list of permutations. In order to make that work you would need to add the list of permutations as a parameter to your recursive function. And the list would need to be instantiated by the caller.

So I think your function should be declared like this:

```
public static void DoPermute(List<long> Permutations, ref byte[] digits, 
    ref int n, ref int i)
```

The code inside the function can remain largely unchanged and just needs to pass around the list whenever it makes a recursive call. I won't repeat your code here because I think should be obvious what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, David. I followed your advice - stripped out the property and constructor and instead declared a `BuildPermutationList` static method that instantiates a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a `NullReferenceException` beacuse your list is not initialized.
This code should solve it;

```
/// <summary>
/// Computes a permutation of ... 
/// </summary>
class Permutation
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Permutation"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Permutation()
    {
        Permutations = new List<long>(20); // you can set here your capacity.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds permutations of a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="digits">The digits</param>
    /// <param name="n">The n</param>
    /// <param name="i">The i</param>
    public void DoPermute(ref byte[] digits, ref int n, ref int i)
    {
        if (i == n)
        {
            long temp = Numbers.JoinDigits(digits);
            Permutations.Add(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
                int temp = i + 1;
                DoPermute(ref digits, ref n, ref temp);
                SwapValues(ref digits, ref i, ref j);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the permuation result.
    /// </summary>
    public List<long> Permutations { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I solved it by declaring the DoPermute() method as static and instead of the constructor writing another static method that first instantiates a list, calls `DoPermute` and ultimately returns the list.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, though. Really appreciate it.